# Converting WSResponse to Result: Recovering lost session key-value from result

Tags: scala, playframework, play-ws

I have endpoint which I'll denote as `/endpoint` which does something like this

```
def endPoint() = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val result: Result = Ok("Done")
  result.addingToSession("Key" -> "Value"): Result
}
```

When I send a `WSRequest` to the endpoint and get the `WSResponse` back, I can't seem to find the `"Key","Value"` pair that was added to the session in `WSResponse`.

I need it in order to use the key,value pair in subsequent WSRequests.

Can someone explain why this is the case and if there is a way to recover this?

(It would be great if someone can point me to the link where this(the result -> WSResponse conversion) is explained)

I thought of parsing the `WSRequest` as `Result`, but I am not sure if it'll recover the lost field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A bit of explanation of what's under the hood**

Between your client and your server, there's only plain standard HTTP requests and responses, there's no Play objects.

When the server returns a `Result`, this result is transformed by Play HTTP server to a HTTP standard response.

In your client code, the `WSResponse` is kinda the opposite: the client library received a standard HTTP response and transformed it in a `WSResponse` for you to manipulate it as a Scala class.

`Result` and `WSResponse` somehow represent the same thing but in two different context (server vs. client). There's no reason to try to convert one into the other.

---

**Back to your question**, your server endpoint returns the following HTTP response:

- `Ok(...)`: code 200 (OK)
- `"Done"`: body in plain text (without the quotes) as you didn't specify JSON or something else
- and `addingToSession("Key" -> "Value")` which as the name suggest use a Play server specific behaviour where some data are added to a "session" object that is sent back on each subsequent request and that the server may read to provide a response.

**In the standard HTTP response, there's no such thing as a session**. The session data is actually stored in a cookie named `SESSION` (by default) which itself is set through the HTTP response special header `Set-Cookie: ...`.

What does it mean for your client code? It means that if you want to read this key-value, you need to retrieve the cookie from the `WSResponse` and then parse it and extract the data.

Now, there are several issues with this approach:

- the cookie value is potentially encoded and/or encrypted in a way that makes it only readable from the server (or knowing a secret value of the server). In practice, it's a JWT token in latest versions, so it would be readable.
- the actual implementation of the session cookie (even the name) might change when Play version is upgraded on the server and your client code would be broken
- **session cookie is meant as a way to share data between subsequent requests to the server and for the server, not to share data between the server and the client**

---

**What you probably want instead:**

Return the key-value information in the body of the HTTP response, for instance in JSON:

```scala
Ok(Json.toJson(Map("key" -> "value")))
```

And in your client code:

```
val map = wsResponse.body.as[Map[String, String]]
map.get("key")
```

Another option, if for some reason you don't want to use the response body, would be to use HTTP headers. Headers are key-value that you can set on the server response and easily read on the client response.

---

*Edit: I hadn't read the part where you say you need to send back the key-value on subsequent requests.*

**If you actually are not interested in the key-value excepted to send it back in subsequent requests**, thus using the session can make sense and you only need to retrieve the cookie in the response and add it back to next request:

```scala
val sessionCookie = wsResponse.cookies.get("SESSION")

// Next request
wsRequest.addCookie(sessionCooKie).get
```

*(Method names are approximative, check the documentation or your IDE will help)*

Still, IMHO, using Play's session mechanism for this is not ideal. Depending on your exact use case (authentication?), I would implement something dedicated to it.